# Is it possible to get scrobbles and listeners from the Last.FM API?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, last.fm

I am using Python to gather information in Artists.

Among other sources I want to use Last.FM an scrape information on Scrobbles and Listeners per Artist.

Can somebody tell me whether this is possible via an API or whether I should give BeautifulSoup a shot and parse the HTML?

I am already using the pylast module for Python but could not figure out how it should work.

Comment: Have you tried: http://www.last.fm/api/show/artist.getInfo ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with pylast:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pylast

# You have to have your own unique two values for API_KEY and API_SECRET
# Obtain yours from http://www.last.fm/api/account for Last.fm
API_KEY = "TODO_ENTER_YOURS"
API_SECRET = "TODO_ENTER_YOURS"

lastfm_network = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key = API_KEY, api_secret = API_SECRET)

artist = lastfm_network.get_artist("Test Artist")

print "Listeners:", artist.get_listener_count()
print "Scrobbles:", artist.get_playcount()
```

Outputs:

```
Listeners: 851
Scrobbles: 3434
```